# var_dump почему то выводит массив только если я отправляю поле со значением из списка,а я хочу что бы сразу выводился var_dump без нажатия на кнопку

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "regauth") or die("Error!!!");
    
    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
        header("location: ../../");
    
    if($_GET['link'] === 'logout'){
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        session_destroy();
        header("location: ../../");
    }
    // $formdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
      $len=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameselect']));
    // $names = $formdata['nameselect'];
    // $names_str = implode(', ', $names);
    
        if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,email,img,len) VALUES ('$login', '$password','$name','$email','$img','$len') ");  
     }
    
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Личный кабинет</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div><?php echo "Привет, ".$_SESSION['user'][1]; ?> | <a href="index.php?link=logout">Выйти</a>
    </div>
    <h3>Создание заявки</h3>
    <form  method="post">
    <p><select size="3" name="nameselect" multiple>
        <option value="Тест1">Тест1</option>
        <option value="Тест2">Тест2</option>
        <option value="Тест3">Тест3</option>
       </select></p>
       <p><input type="submit" name="do-len"value="Отправить"></p>
       </form>
       <h3>Просмотр своих записей на курсы</h3>
      <?php
    
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `len` = '$len'");
    $result = $sql->fetch_all();
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Сделайте читабельный заголовок

Comment: Cейчас понятно?

Comment: нет, вопрос в теле сообщения должен быть, а не в заголовке))

Comment: вряд ли инструкция `INSERT INTO users (login...` работает

Comment: Заголовок всё ещё перегружен. Вынесите часть информации в описание

Comment: var_dump($result); почему то выводит массив только если я отправляю поле со значением из списка,а хочу что бы сразу выводился var_dump без нажатия на кнопку

Comment: а что должно быть в $len, если не было выбрано значение из списка??? Вот ответ на этот вопрос дайте себе и станет ясно, почему ничего не выводится.

Comment: Такие паровозы не летают. Без нажатия на кнопку не будет отправки на сервер, а var_dump выполняется на сервере. Если очень хочется -- перейти на ajax.